# Print ftp name and password data

Tags: python, ftp

I am using this python 2.7 script to listen on port 21. Now I need to echo username and password when user tries to connect via ftp client. 
What should I change in my script?

```
import socket
import sys

HOST = ''   # Symbolic name, meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 21 # Arbitrary non-privileged port

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print 'Socket created'

#Bind socket to local host and port
try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as msg:
    print 'Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()

print 'Socket bind complete'

#Start listening on socket
s.listen(10)
print 'Socket now listening'

#now keep talking with the client
while 1:
    #wait to accept a connection - blocking call
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])

s.close()
```

Comment: Now you have to receive your data and interpret it. You can use `recv()` for that ([see](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To receive data from a client, you can use `recv()`. The *socket* module proposes also other similar functions. You can refer to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html) for more precisions.

As you are at a low level, you have to interpret yourself the [FTP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol) ([list of commands](http://www.nsftools.com/tips/RawFTP.htm)).

Comment: I posted this as it seems to be useful for the OP regarding his answer to my comment! So why have I a -1?